# Javascript convert array with null value to string

Tags: javascript

I have the array

```
localCostp:
  0:null
  1:null
  2:0.5
  3:null
  4:null
  5:null
  6:0.5
  7:null
  8:null
```

and i would like to convert it in a string like the below

```
"[],[],[0.5],[],[],[],[0.5],[],[]"
```

i have tried the below

```
console.log("[" + Object.values(localCostp).join("],[") + "]");
```

but i lose the null value

```
"[0.5],[0.5]"
```

i fill the array with the below code

```
    Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
       var r=[],c = this.slice(0);
        for (let i = c.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [c[i], c[j]] = [c[j], c[i]];
        }
        return c;
    }; 

    Array.prototype.populateUnique = function(n) {
    return Object.keys( Object( 0+Array(n) ) );
    };

    var getRandomInts = function(num, min, max) {
        var a = [].populateUnique(max+1).slice(min);
        a = a.shuffle();
        return a.slice(0,num);
    };

    BordsIdtoFill  = getRandomInts(NumOfBoardToFill,1,6);

       switch(retrivePanelsPanelsbetType(configGenerateData.panelsBetType)) {
    case 1: case 2:{   
        gameMultiplayer      = 1;
    } break;
    case 3: case 4 : case 5: {
       gameMultiplayer      = 2;    
    } break;
    case 6:  {            
        gameMultiplayer      = 2;
    } break;
}
```

var localCostp  = new Array(9);

```
    BordsIdtoFill.forEach(function(Bord) {
      localCostp[Bord]= (1*gameMultiplayer * 0.5)
    });

console.log("[" + Object.values(localCostp).join("],[") + "]");
```

not all the array position are filled

Comment: *"i have tried the below"* That [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/cdw4e95z/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naive way of doing would be to

```js
const arr = [null, null, 0.5, null, 0.5]

const processedArr = arr.map(element => {
  if (element) {
    return [element];
  } else {
    return [];
  }
});

const result = JSON.stringify(processedArr);
console.log(result)
```

A shorter, but less readable way of doing it will be to use the following:

```js
const arr = [null, null, 0.5, null, 0.5];
const result = `[[${arr.join('],[')}]]`;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: if i use your code with your array inizialization all work correctly but 
if i inizialize and fill the array programmatically i take the below 

null,[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],null,null

i fill the array with the below code 

var localCostp  = new Array(9);

BordsIdtoFill.forEach(function(Bord) {
  localCostp[Bord]= (1*gameMultiplayer * 0.5)
});


not all the array position are filled

Comment: Sorry, ermm.. Let me try and run the code you provided. Meanwhile, I have provided an alternative solution, which is shorter, faster, but less readible.

Comment: is `gameMultiplayer` any integer?

Answer (score 2):

That's interesting output. :-)

In a comment you've said:

> i fill the array with the below code
>
> ```
> var localCostp = new Array(9);
> BordsIdtoFill.forEach(function(Bord) {
>     localCostp[Bord] = (1*gameMultiplayer * 0.5);
> });
> ```
>
> not all the array position are filled

That's **very** different from the array you showed. The array you showed had `null`s in it. That array has *gaps* in it. When you read the value of a gap, you get back `undefined` (not `null`).

To do it, you'll either want to use a simple `for` loop, a `for-of` loop or something other way of using the iterable from `values` (which includes gaps), or fill the gaps first.

For instance, this uses the iterable from `values`:

```
const string = [...localCostp.values()].map(entry => JSON.stringify(entry === undefined ? [] : [entry])).join();
```

Live Example:

```js
const localCostp = new Array(9);
localCostp[2] = 0.5;
localCostp[6] = 0.5;

const string = [...localCostp.values()].map(entry => JSON.stringify(entry === undefined ? [] : [entry])).join();
console.log(string);
```

In another comment you've said:

> if i run your code on my enviroment i take There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script: TypeError: localCostp.values(...)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

That's surprising, `values` was added in ES2015, the same time Symbol.iterator and array spread were, but your error message makes it seem like you have the latter but not the former. I suspect you're transpiling and missing a polyfill.

Here's an ES5 version (can't use `map` because it won't visit the gaps):

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < localCostp.length; ++i) {
    var entry = localCostp[i];
    result[i] = JSON.stringify(entry === undefined ? [] : [entry]);
}
result = result.join();
```

Live Example:

```js
var localCostp = new Array(9);
localCostp[2] = 0.5;
localCostp[6] = 0.5;

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < localCostp.length; ++i) {
    var entry = localCostp[i];
    result[i] = JSON.stringify(entry === undefined ? [] : [entry]);
}
result = result.join();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: if i use your code with your array inizialization all work correctly but 
if i inizialize and fill the array programmatically i take the below 

null,[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],null,null

i fill the array with the below code 

var localCostp  = new Array(9);

BordsIdtoFill.forEach(function(Bord) {
  localCostp[Bord]= (1*gameMultiplayer * 0.5)
});


not all the array position are filled

Comment: @LucaRuggeri - That's not an array with `null`s, that's an array with *gaps*. Reading a gap gives you the value `undefined` (not `null`). Why not just show us how you were creating it in the first place?

Comment: edit my post with the code that create and populate the array

Comment: sorry but when i console.log the array i take null value that .... if i run your code on my enviroment i take There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  TypeError: localCostp.values(...)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

Comment: @LucaRuggeri - That's surprising, `values` was added in ES2015, the same time Symbol.iterator was, but your error message makes it seem like you have the latter but not the former. Are you using transpiling and missing a polyfill? I'll add an ES5 solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to produce either `[]` for `null` value or enclose the number in square brackets, then [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the desired output:

```js
let arr = [
  null,
  null,
  0.5,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  0.5,
  null,
  null
]

let str = arr
  .map(item => item === null ? "[]" : `[${item}]`)
  .join();

console.log(str);
```

Comment: if i use your code with your array inizialization all work correctly but 
if i inizialize and fill the array programmatically i take the below 

null,[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],null,null

i fill the array with the below code 

var localCostp  = new Array(9);

BordsIdtoFill.forEach(function(Bord) {
  localCostp[Bord]= (1*gameMultiplayer * 0.5)
});


not all the array position are filled

Answer (score 0):

You could map the values in an array or not and stringify the data and get the string between the outer brackets.

```js
var data = [null, null, 0.5, null, null, null, 0.5, null, null],
    result = JSON.stringify(data.map(v => v === null ? [] : [v])).slice(1, -1);

console.log(result);
```

An example with template strings.

```js
var data = [null, null, 0.5, null, null, null, 0.5, null, null],
    result = data.map(v => `[${v === null ? '' : v}]`).join();

console.log(result);
```

With an array with sparse items.

```js
var array = [, , 0.5, , , , 0.5, , ],
    result = Array.from(array, (v = '') => `[${v}]`).join();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: if i use your code with your array inizialization all work correctly but 
if i inizialize and fill the array programmatically i take the below 

null,[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],[0.5],null,null

i fill the array with the below code 

var localCostp  = new Array(9);

BordsIdtoFill.forEach(function(Bord) {
  localCostp[Bord]= (1*gameMultiplayer * 0.5)
});


not all the array position are filled